type declaration file in @types only working when using declare module syntax
I've been investigating what appears to be a strange behavior with the @types/tedious package from DefinitelyTyped:
import { ColumnValue } from "tedious"; // Error: Module '"tedious"' has no exported member 'ColumnValue'.

However, looking into the index.d.ts under node_modules/@types/tedious I can see that the type does exist and is exported on line 427. I manually changed this file to:
declare module "tedious" {
  // Everything
}

And now ColumnValue is correctly detected and used.
Great! So now I assumed this can be fixed by opening a pull request to DefinitelyTyped and adding this syntax to the source code. However, as soon as I do I get an error from the linter saying @definitelytyped/no-declare-current-package, which I take it to mean that declare module should never be necessary anyways.
I am a little confused as to why this is happening, and why Typescript cannot correctly detect a package from @types, when all the documentation I've read suggests that this should be the default behavior.
In case it is important, here is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "lib": ["es2015"]
}

package.json:
{
  "name": "tedious test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.14.11",
    "@types/tedious": "^4.0.14",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tedious": "^18.2.4"
  }
}

I've also tried restarting the TS server, but no change.
